# Recaptcha2 'non-object' error in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, recaptcha

I'm trying to implement a Recaptcha2 in an old project that uses Zend. I'm using this library for it https://packagist.org/packages/cgsmith/zf1-recaptcha-2

Initially I was getting this error

```
Uncaught Zend_Exception: No entry is registered for key 'application'
```

In my `_initRecaptcha`, I changed the first line from

```
$config = \Zend_Registry::get('application');
```

to

```
$config = \Zend_Registry::get('config')->application;
```

This is my `_initRecaptcha` now

```
public function _initRecaptcha()
{
    $config = \Zend_Registry::get('config')->application;
    $params = $config->recaptcha->toArray();

    $params['messageTemplates'] = [
        \Cgsmith\Validate\Recaptcha::INVALID_CAPTCHA => 'The captcha was invalid', // set custom/translated message
        \Cgsmith\Validate\Recaptcha::CAPTCHA_EMPTY => 'The captcha must be completed'
    ];

    \Zend_Registry::set('recaptcha', $params);
}
```

But now I am getting this error

```
Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/my-site/application/Bootstrap.php on line 79
```

Line 79 is the first line in `_initRecaptcha`

Can anyone what I need to change?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The library seems to be assuming your config is stored in the registry under the key 'application' (which seems questionable to me). You could either add a method to your bootstrap that sets this up (see their example: https://github.com/cgsmith/zf1-recaptcha-2/blob/master/example/application/Bootstrap.php#L13-L18), or change the code to not require it:

```
public function _initRecaptcha()
{
    $params = $this->getOptions()['recaptcha'];

    $params['messageTemplates'] = [
        \Cgsmith\Validate\Recaptcha::INVALID_CAPTCHA => 'The captcha was invalid', // set custom/translated message
        \Cgsmith\Validate\Recaptcha::CAPTCHA_EMPTY => 'The captcha must be completed'
    ];

    \Zend_Registry::set('recaptcha', $params);
}
```

(It's a long time since I used ZF1 but I think that should work.)

Both cases assume you've added recaptcha lines to your `application.ini` per the library instructons.